# Confusion about the tensor Frobenius product and index notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products, tensors

Consider the identity $$B \circ A = A : \mathbb{T}: B$$

where A, B, and M are matrices and $\mathbb{T}$ is a tensor of order 6. The tensor is defined as

$$\mathbb{T}_{jklmnp} = 1$$

if $j = k = l$ and $m = n = p$. It is $0$ otherwise. Futhermore, $:$ denotes the Frobenius product and $\circ$ is the Hadamard product. I have been trying to convince myself of the validity of this expression using index notation.

What I would like clarification on is the standard way of contracting indices. When I write out the equation in index notation I get

$$(B \circ A)_{iq} = B_{ij} \mathbb{T}_{jklmnp} A_{pq}$$

Is this the correct way to contract the indices ? If so, why isn't any other contraction of the indices (say, exchanging p and q) valid?

Sorry if this is a repeat question, I tried searching before posting. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might make things clearer to write the expression with explicit summations: 
$$\sum_i\sum_j\sum_m\sum_n B_{ij}{\mathbb T}_{ijklmn}A_{mn}$$
Then when you're ready, you can remove the training wheels (aka sigmas).

Comment: Thank you Lynn, I took your advice. Looks like I’ll need to keep the wheels on for a bit longer.